# Why does setTimeout trigger instantly?

Tags: javascript

I found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout1) `setTimeout()` method example on W3 Schools and noticed something that I cannot explain. The example is:

```
myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
```

...which works fine. But when I change it to

```
myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc(), 3000);
```

...the alert triggers instantly. Why? Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: Why should adding the parenthesis change nothing ? They're not some kind of decoration, they mean "call the function"

Comment: There *has* to be a good dupe target for this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can't find one buddy.

Comment: -10 damn... was it so obvious ^^?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> shouldn´t it be the same?

No, not at all.

`setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000)` passes the value of `alertFunc` (a reference to a function) into `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` stores that function reference in order to call it three seconds later.

`setTimeout(alertFunc(), 3000)` **calls** `alertFunc`, immediately, and passes its *return value* into `setTimeout`. Exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

Comment: What does "community wiki" mean?

Comment: @evolutionxbox http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 3):

The `setTimeout()` accepts a function as a first parameter and the time as the second parameter. I hope you have heard of functions returning a function as well. So for that cases, you can also call the function there.

The moment you add `()` to any function, it calls it immediately. So you call the function and return nothing to execute to the `setTimeout`.

**Case 1**

```
setTimeout(myFunc, 3000);
```

Here you are passing the **function itself** to get executed after 3 seconds.

**Case 2**

```
setTimeout(myFunc(), 3000);
```

Here you are passing the **function's executed return value** to get executed after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc(), 3000);` is the same as:
`aF = alertFunc(); myVar = setTimeout(aF, 3000);`

From this you can see that `alertFunc` is called outside of `setTimeout`.